# What should I do so Ubuntu finds a new application when pressing Alt+F2?

Tags: ubuntu

I've got a new machine running Ubuntu 14.4 today, and I installed
Eclipse by downloading and unzipping it.

Now I would like to be able to:

1. run the command `eclipse` in the terminal to open Eclipse;
2. search for it using Alt+F2 and typing "eclipse".

I added the eclipse directory in the path environment, this solved my
requirement (1).

Eclipse has a `.desktop` file, so it can be put into to the
launcher. But I still can't use Alt+F2 to open the command "screen"
and find it by typing `eclipse`. Is there any procedure I have to
follow so Ubuntu finds the Eclipse in the "run a command" screen just
like it finds Firefox, with an icon and everything?

Also, what is the screen that appears after pressing Alt+F2 called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the new directory to your `PATH` environment variable temporarily, the command launcher window (Alt-F2) will not find it. You have to make the `PATH` modification in your startup dot-files (usually `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`), then you have to log out and log back in for the change to take effect for all new shells. After the re-login, you should be able to start it by typing "eclipse" in the command launcher window.

Comment: I did this changing the /etc/environment. Yes, I am able to call it using the launcher due to the path variable, but I would like it to look like Chrome,  Firefox or any other application, that has an Icon and can be easily identified

Comment: In that case, I would say you'd be better off installing eclipse from the Ubuntu repositories than downloading and unzipping. If you need a specific version of eclipse for some reason, then keep the downloaded version, and see http://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse for more details about how to make the `.desktop` file work.

Comment: great! This is exactly whats I needed!  Thanks!