# I installed Eclipse, how do I make it searchable?

Tags: linux-mint, menu, .desktop

I downloaded the installer and installed Eclipse to my Downloads directory.  I also added the path to my Path variable so when I open a terminal and type eclipse, it runs.  However, when I open the menu in Linux Mint and search for Eclipse it doesn't show up.  I read here that in Ubuntu that should be enough, but I suppose in Mint it's not: [What should I do so Ubuntu finds a new application when pressing Alt+F2?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197465/what-should-i-do-so-ubuntu-finds-a-new-application-when-pressing-altf2)

I created a `.desktop` file under `~/.local/share/applications` but that didn't fix the problem, not sure if it should have--I'm not super clear on what these files do.

[Edit: The `.desktop` file is `eclipse.desktop` and contains

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Exec=/home/user/Downloads/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

]

Comment: What does your "eclipse.desktop" file look like?  What did you add to it?

Comment: @bgregs I added the info to the post.

Comment: Try adding the file to /usr/share/applications/ .  See this for reference: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1504

Answer (score 0):

Using @bgregs suggestion, I moved the `eclipse.desktop` file to /usr/share/applications.  It still didn't work but then I realize that you need to not just point the `.desktop` file to the *folder* containing the binary, but to the binary itself.  So rather than

```
Exec=/home/user/Downloads/eclipse
```

I needed

```
Exec=/home/user/Downloads/eclipse/eclipse
```